# Unable to set temperature on Nest rest API

Tags: java, python, curl, nest-api

My developers permissions are set to:

- Away - read/write v2
- Energy - read v2
- ETA - read v1
- Postal code - read v2
- Structure - read/write v1
- Thermostat read/write v6

I can get the temperature easily:

```
$ curl -s -L -X GET "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/ADK.....-/target_temperature_c" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvC....."
$ 11.0
```

However I'm consistently getting an "Invalid content sent" response when trying to set the temperature. This is consistent whether I use Curl, Java, python, etc.. I've tried requests in each of the following formats (And more besides, but the below were various examples found in documentation and here on SO)

```
# With Auth Token in URL
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-/target_temperature_c?auth=c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d     "10"

# Without write target in URL
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"target_temperature_c\":10}"

# Without write target in URL, not escaping quotes
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"target_temperature_c":10}'

# With write target in URL
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-/target_temperature_c" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "10"

# Try and set a String field instead
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-/label" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "A Label"

# Try it without Json as a content type
curl -s -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostat/ADK.....-/label" -H "Authorization: Bearer c.IQvCNgfU......" -d "A Label"
```

Here's the error response in full:

```
{"error":"Invalid content sent","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#invalid-content-sent","message":"Invalid content sent","instance":"91c86174-576d-43b7-a586-fcc07a92efa5"}
```

Comment: What happens when you try setting the Fahrenheit bucket with a Fahrenheit value?

Comment: Same response. I've also tried setting the 'label' to see if it was a number formatting issue. See 'try and set a string field instead'

Comment: You're missing an "s" in thermostats. Should behttps://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/ADK... etc etc

Comment: JTFC............ Hours I spent fiddling with the damn authentication and formatting. I've added the 's' and am now dealing with a "not found" error. I'll keep at it and post a new one if I'm still stuck in a..... week..... Thank you!

Comment: Got it. Finally working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @urman kindly spotted, I was missing an 's' in "thermostat**s**" in the set request. Words cannot express the embarrassment:)

As a request for any Nest developers reading - could a different error message be returned? Even a 404 would point to something more obviously wrong in the url vs the "content".

Comment: no problem! It's happened to all of us. You are correct however that the API should have returned a 404 which makes much more sense.